# How can I start different mode with Emacs in command line?

Tags: emacs, mode

Is there a way to start different emacs mode using command line? For example, is it possible to run emacs as follows?

```
   emacs --org-mode # to start orgmode
   emacs --python-mode # to start python mode
```

I can just run emacs to input 'M-x org-mode' thereafter, but I wonder if I can start different modes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can call functions with the -f argument, so to start org-mode use:

```
emacs -f org-mode
```