# Select custom emacs major mode at command line

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have created my own major mode in emacs for editing certain files. I would like to select this mode from the command line (the mode works fine if I `auto-load` it from within my Emacs init file (`~/.emacs`). I have tried the following (see [How can I start different mode with Emacs in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879365/how-can-i-start-different-mode-with-emacs-in-command-line) ) :

```
emacs -f my-mode file &
```

but nothing happens. (I have stored my mode file in `~/emacs/my-mode.el`.)

(I have also tried `emacs -f matlab-mode file` just to see if there is something wrong with my particular mode file, but I do not get `matlab-mode` either)

I am using GNU Emacs 23.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Note that you *did* run the function you specified; just not in the buffer you wanted to run it in. Check the `*scratch*` buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of arguments matters.
This works for me:

```
emacs test.org -f c++-mode &
```